# I read a flv file header using ReadU8 function,but sometimes not work well

Tags: c++, video, mp4, flv

Some flv  I can read the header using `ReadU8`, it gives **9**.

But sometimes a flv file that is converted to mp4 file will give **73** using the `readU8`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Is this Python? Try to improve this Question's explanation. Right now it makes no sense. For example an FLV header has total 9 bytes length & looks like this `46 4C 56 01 01 00 00 00 09` so the only way you will get _"9"_ is by reading the last (9th) byte in header section. Now _"...a flv file that translated by mp4 file give 73"_ is confusing. Can you show an example or explain better? If _"translate"_ means _convert_ then understand the information has changed, it's not FLV anymore.

Comment: Thank yoou for answer and sorry for the cunfusing of the question.I mean a flv file that converted by mp4 file .If a mp4 file was converted to flv file,what actually file is is? by the way,I'm using c++.if it  is a mp4 file ,how can i get the video data in the file?thank you

Comment: What does your function with `readU8` look like? Use this [**`EDIT`**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41492374/edit) link to add the code. This **9** or **73** from a byte, is it the hex values or decimal values? For one FLV and one MP4... Tell me what is results of `readU8` for bytes 1-2-3-4? This means read at pointer offsets `[0]` `[1]` `[2]` `[3]`.